# Use value from the previous row for manipulation of multiple column at once in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi everyone I need a help.
I have the data-set similar to this which contain multiple rows and columns.

```
df<- data.frame(A=seq(0.01,0.05,0.01),
            B=c(0.01, -0.24, 0, -0.21, 0), 
            C=seq(0.03,0.07,0.01),
            D=c(0.4,0.5,0,0,2))
```

I used shift command and created another row E.

```
df[ , E := shift(A)+A]
```

Now I want to apply similar function to whole data frame df and create row F, G, H similar to E using similar method at once.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are using `data.table`, the `shift` can take multiple columns at once and output the `lag` of those.  If we are not selecting any particular sets of columns, specifying `shift(.SD)` (`.SD` represents the Subset of Data.table) gives the `lag` of all the columns in the dataset.  By assigning (`:=`) it to different column names (`LETTERS[5:8]`), we get a new set of lag columns in the original dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, LETTERS[5:8] := shift(.SD)+.SD]
df
#     A     B    C   D    E     F    G   H
#1: 0.01  0.01 0.03 0.4   NA    NA   NA  NA
#2: 0.02 -0.24 0.04 0.5 0.03 -0.23 0.07 0.9
#3: 0.03  0.00 0.05 0.0 0.05 -0.24 0.09 0.5
#4: 0.04 -0.21 0.06 0.0 0.07 -0.21 0.11 0.0
#5: 0.05  0.00 0.07 2.0 0.09 -0.21 0.13 2.0
```

Or we can loop through `lapply`

```
setDT(df)[, LETTERS[5:8] := lapply(.SD, function(x) x+shift(x))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative for this:

```
new_cols <- c('E','F','G','H')

old_cols <- colnames(df)

for (i in seq_along(new_cols)){

    eval(parse(text = paste0("df[,",new_cols[i],":= shift(",old_cols[i],")+",old_cols[i],"]")))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The answer helped me solve my problem.